# How to add a value for repetition?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Excuse if the title doesn't suit

I'm having a table as following

```
Dev     FCNo    DateTime
dev1    1   12-06-2020
dev1    2   12-06-2020
dev1    3   13-06-2020
dev1    4   14-06-2020
dev1    5   15-06-2020
dev1    6   15-06-2020
dev1    7   16-06-2020
dev1    1   16-06-2020
dev1    2   16-06-2020
dev1    3   17-06-2020
dev1    4   17-06-2020
dev2    1   12-06-2020
dev2    2   12-06-2020
dev2    3   13-06-2020
dev2    1   13-06-2020
dev2    2   13-06-2020
dev2    3   14-06-2020
```

I want a column as

```
Dev     FCNo    DateTime    Occurance
dev1    1   12-06-2020      1
dev1    2   12-06-2020      1
dev1    3   13-06-2020      1
dev1    4   14-06-2020      1
dev1    5   15-06-2020      1
dev1    6   15-06-2020      1
dev1    7   16-06-2020      1
dev1    1   16-06-2020      2
dev1    2   16-06-2020      2
dev1    3   17-06-2020      2
dev1    4   17-06-2020      2
dev2    1   12-06-2020      1
dev2    2   12-06-2020      1
dev2    3   13-06-2020      1
dev2    1   13-06-2020      2
dev2    2   13-06-2020      2
dev2    3   14-06-2020      2
```

Whenever the FCNo repeats as 1 for a particular device the Occurance should be increased. How to achieve this in SQL

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query,

```
select dev, fcno, datetime, rnk
from
(select dev, fcno, datetime, row_number() over(partition by dev, fcno) as rnk
from table_name) qry order by dev, fcno;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by fcno, dev order by datetime) as occurrence
from t;
```